# Bind error. not loaded due to errors

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, bind, dns-hosting, dns-zone

I don't what happend. I am very new to DNS and Bind. I am getting below error:

```
[root@centos-abcd~]# sudo named-checkzone abcd.abcd.pw /etc/named/zones/db.abcd.abcd.pw
/etc/named/zones/db.abcd.abcd.pw:4: ignoring out-of-zone data (abcd.pw)
/etc/named/zones/db.abcd.abcd.pw:5: ignoring out-of-zone data (abcd.pw)
/etc/named/zones/db.abcd.abcd.pw:6: ignoring out-of-zone data (abcd.pw)
/etc/named/zones/db.abcd.abcd.pw:7: ignoring out-of-zone data (abcd.pw)
/etc/named/zones/db.abcd.abcd.pw:8: ignoring out-of-zone data (abcd.pw)
zone abcd.abcd.pw/IN: has 0 SOA records
zone abcd.abcd.pw/IN: has no NS records
zone abcd.abcd.pw/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

This is my named.conf.local file:

```
zone "abcd.abcd.pw" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/named/zones/db.abcd.abcd.pw"; # zone file path
};
```

and this is my zone file:

```
$TTL 1800
$ORIGIN abcd.pw.

abcd.pw. IN SOA ns1.digitalocean.com. hostmaster.abcd.pw. 1471256742 10800 3600 604800 1800
abcd.pw. 1800 IN NS ns1.digitalocean.com.
abcd.pw. 1800 IN NS ns2.digitalocean.com.
abcd.pw. 1800 IN NS ns3.digitalocean.com.
abcd.pw. 1800 IN A 128.199.193.42
```

what may be the error and how can I solve it, plz suggest..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the defined zone in named.conf.local is abcd.abcd.pw while the RR are for abcd.pw only.

So either rename the zone in named.conf.local to be: `zone "abcd.pw" {`

Or modify the zone file replacing the abcd.pw with abcd.abcd.pw